# Run VBS files (iMacros script) from an other iMacros script

Tags: vbscript, imacros

All is in the title. I want to run VBS files (several iMacros script) from one iMacros script.

I know nothing in iMacros language and syntax but I made this :

```
option explicit
randomize

Dim iim1, iret

Set iim1 = createobject("imacros")

iret = iim1.iimOpen("-ie -ieprivate", true, 300)

Dim launch

launch = launch + "url goto = http://lequipe.fr" + vbNewLine

iret = iim1.iimPlayCode(launch)
```

This code open IE in private then launch http://lequipe.fr but I don't know how to run files with iMacros syntax.

In VBS this would be something like that :

```
Dim WshShell, i, count

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

i = 1
count = 3

While i <= count
    If i = 1 Then
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Quentin\Desktop\iMacro\testequipe.vbs"
    Else If i = 2 Then
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Quentin\Desktop\iMacro\testprogres.vbs"
    Else If i = 3 Then
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Quentin\Desktop\iMacro\testmonde.vbs"
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Perhaps you have to apply the [iimPlay() function](http://wiki.imacros.net/iimPlay()) .

Comment: Is this possible ? I search my problem and I found a similar post but one of the answers said that is not possible to run external file (like a VBS file) with an iMacros program

Comment: This may be possible with 'iMacros for Firefox'. However I still don't comprehend clear what you're attempting to do.

Comment: @Shugar , I want to execute several VBS programs, not IIM programs.

Comment: Take a look at sample codes [here](http://wiki.imacros.net/Sample_Code#VBS_.28Visual_Basic_Scripting.29). You actually use the Scripting Interface of VBS to control 'iim'-macros, so why not to execute several VBS programs from VBS as well?

Comment: @Shugar , I finally found a solution :)